# OpenCover & ReportGenerator : How to generate one html report from xml file

Tags: code-coverage, opencover, partcover, reportgenerator

I have generated xml file using OpenCover. And used below command to generate html report,

```
"C:\ReportGenerator_2.1.4.0\bin\ReportGenerator.exe" -reports:"Reports\Test.xml" -targetdir:"Reports"
```

It generated multiple html reports under 'Reports' folder. I wanted to generate one 'Test.html' report. I tried many options but did not work. Could you please tell me which option I should use to generate one 'Test.html' report.

Comment: I don't think that option is available - why do you need one report? You could write your own see [Custom reports](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Custom-reports)

Comment: Method coverage with reportGenerator needs payment https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/65d31c6f41bcb73061c9d314d62abafb#file-reportgenerator-needs-payment-md

Answer (score 4):

You can use the report type *HtmlSummary*. This creates a single file report:

```
"C:\ReportGenerator_2.1.4.0\bin\ReportGenerator.exe" -reports:"Reports\Test.xml" -targetdir:"Reports" -reporttypes:HtmlSummary
```

If you want to customize the report, you can implement a plugin which renders the report. See https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Custom-reports.

Comment: awesome as ever @Daniel

Comment: Helpful. Just wanted to add this reference https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator